# Combining multiple scalar bigquery queries into a single query to generate one table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BiqQuery query that basically takes a date as a parameter and calculates the number of active users our app had near that date.

Right now, if I want to make a graph over a year of active users, I have to run the query 12 times (once per month) and collate the results manually, which is error-prone and time consuming.

Is there a way to make a single bigquery query that runs the subquery 12 times and puts the results on 12 different rows?

For example, if my query is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE activityTime < date '2017-01-01'
```

How can I get a table like

```
| Date       |  Count  |
|------------|---------|
| 2017-01-01 |  50000  |
| 2017-02-01 |  40000  |
| 2017-03-01 |  30000  |
| 2017-04-01 |  20000  |
| 2017-05-01 |  10000  |
```

Comment: can you show us your query?

Comment: Yes, I should have done that, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elliot taught me `UNION ALL` and it seemed to do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE activityTime < date '2017-01-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE activityTime < date '2017-02-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE activityTime < date '2017-03-01'
```

Maybe there's a nicer way to parameterize the dates in the WHERE clause, but this did the trick for me.

Comment: This is my new favorite SQL operator.

Comment: Note @charlesreid1 i found a _way_ better solution than this using cross join! Basically `select d from unnest(generate_date_array('2017-01-01','2017-12-01', interval 1 month) as d cross join $myQuery where activityTime < d group by d`

Comment: Oh wow - Cartesian product of tables - way cool. SQL continues to amaze me.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have a column called `date` and one called `user_id` and you want to calculate distinct users on a monthly basis, you can run a query such as:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS distinct_users
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month ASC;
```

(Here you can replace `YourTable` with the subquery that you want to run). As a self-contained example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-06-25' AS date, 10 AS user_id UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-05-04', 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-06-20', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-01', 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-06-02', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-13', 10
)
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS distinct_users
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This taught me `UNION ALL` which was the key to my eventual solution, but `GROUP BY month` was not what I needed - I really do need to run multiple separate queries and concatenate them.